# how to set year as time coordinate using netcdf

Tags: python, python-xarray, netcdf4

```
years = range(2011, 2020)
dataset1 = [xr.open_dataset('dataset') for year in years]
dataset1= xr.concat(dataset1, dim='time')


# set year as time coordinate

dataset1= dataset1. assign_coords(year=('time', years))
```

but the error
ValueError: conflicting sizes for dimension 'time': length 9 on 'year' and length 1080 on 'time'

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you have more than one datapoint along the time dimension per year.  One way to address this is by assigning a year coordinate that contains the year of each time in the dataset, despite the fact that it will contain duplicate values.  You can do this with [the `DatetimeAccessor`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.core.accessor_dt.DatetimeAccessor.html):

```py
dataset1 = dataset1.assign_coords(year=dataset1.time.dt.year)
```